# Building boost under msys, can't find mingw.jam

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, bjam

I need to build boost to use the regex library. I was able to creat bjam using bootstrap.sh like so:

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=mingw
```

Note - if I leave out the --with-toolset=mingw argument compilation fails - bootstrap can't find wait.h, resource.h, ar.h. With the mingw toolset argument, bjam is able to compile. Then I run bjam and get:

```
./bjam.exe
mingw.jam: No such file or directory
e:/libraries/boost_1_45_0/tools/build/v2/build\toolset.jam:38: in toolset.using
rule mingw.init unknown in module toolset.
e:/libraries/boost_1_45_0/tools/build/v2/build\project.jam:881: in using
project-config.jam:12: in modules.load
e:/libraries/boost_1_45_0/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:257: in load-config
e:/libraries/boost_1_45_0/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:423: in load-configuration-files
e:/libraries/boost_1_45_0/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:554: in load
e:\libraries\boost_1_45_0\tools\build\v2/kernel\modules.jam:283: in import
e:\libraries\boost_1_45_0\tools\build\v2\kernel\bootstrap.jam:142: in boost-build
e:\libraries\boost_1_45_0\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

I tried several variations of parameters and get the same error:

```
./bjam.exe --build-dir=e:/libraries/boost_1_45_0/ --toolset=mingw
./bjam.exe --build-dir=e:/libraries/boost_1_45_0/ --toolset=gcc
```

Not sure how to get bjam to build. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 28):

Once you have built bjam with `./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=mingw`

Edit the file project-config.jam and replace 'mingw' by 'gcc'

Then launch bjam.exe and it should work